# Nagios e-mail notifications on RPi

Tags: nagios

I have a PC on my network that I want to monitor with a simple periodic ping from a Raspberry Pi. I'm totally new to the RPi and Linux and this seemingly simple project is turning into a massive headache. However, I've made massive progress in installing Nagios PI on the RPi and configuring it to monitor my PC with a periodic ping via NConf.  So within the Nagios GUI I can see when my PC is up and down (this took 2 days to get this far). I also setup e-mail on the RPi using sSMTP and I can send e-mails from the command line (this took another long day).

So all I now need to do is get Nagios/NConf to send me an e-mail when it sees my PC is down. Unfortunately, this is where my luck or talent (or both!) have run out.  Can anyone help point me in the right direction to get these e-mail notifications working within Nagios/NConf please?

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Cheers
Simon

Comment: If not for a learning experience, monitoring a PC with Nagios seems like using a cannon to kill a flea.

Comment: sure it starts out with "just one e-mail" but then 10,000 emails later nagios is all like why don't you talk to me any more?

Comment: Oh dear, I had no idea. What would you recommend to run on the RPi that will notify me once when my PC is down then>?

Answer (score 0):

Nagios uses `contact` definitions that must be linked to the `host` or other such monitoring bit. The `contact` could be placed in in `contacts.cfg` or some other configuration file, depending on how you want to manage things:

```
define contact {
    contact_name foobar
    alias admin of something
    email fixmeyouremailhere@example.net
    host_notification_commands notify-host-by-email
    host_notification_options d,u,r
    host_notification_period 24x7
    service_notification_commands notify-service-by-email
    service_notification_options w,u,c,r
    service_notification_period 24x7
}
```

And then in your `host` definition reference the `contact`:

```
define host {
    host_name ...
    ...
    contacts foobar
}
```

And then restart nagios, fix any errors, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I have contacts_nagio2.cfg in the etc/nagio3/conf.d directory which now looks like this:

define contact {
    contact_name root
    alias Root
    email simon@mydomain.com
    host_notification_commands notify-host-by-email
    host_notification_options d,r
    host_notification_period 24x7
    service_notification_commands notify-service-by-email
    service_notification_options w,u,c,r
    service_notification_period 24x7
}

Comment: I didn’t include the “u” option in host_notification_options as I only want to know when the PC goes down, and not when it’s back online.  I don’t know whether I need to change the contact_name and alias so I left it as default.

Then I don’t have a file called hosts, but I have one called localhost_nagios2.cfg. But in there I only have three “define service” sections. Which file is the host definition in?

Thanks again!

Simon

Comment: Nagios probably includes any `*.cfg` file in the `/etc/nagio3/conf.d` directory automatically, so you likely should create a new `hosts.cfg` in that directory to hold your host definitions.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried that and it still doesn't work. I'm afraid I've spent four days trying to get this to work and I've now run out of time I can spend on it right now. Thanks for trying!